# Load json file from within a zip archive

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Hi I want work on the last file in a zip archive.

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile 
from natsort import natsorted

with ZipFile('1.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
  abc = zipObj.namelist()
  abc =  natsorted(abc, key = str.lower) 
  a22 = abc[-1]  
a22
```

I got:  `"5550.json"`

(btw I work only on numeric json from 1 to 5000-10000)

I created this code to get the last file in the zip archive, but when I try

```py
f = open(a22)
data = json.load(f) 
data
```

but it's different path. Is there another method to get the contents of this json file?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with the `ZipFile.open` method.

For example:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile 
from natsort import natsorted

with ZipFile('1.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
  abc = zipObj.namelist()
  abc =  natsorted(abc, key = str.lower) 
  a22 = abc[-1]  
  info = json.load(zipObj.open(a22))
info
```